# Exclude specific classes and packages within an included jar library for jacoco's covarage check

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I've a java project that produces a .jar library. That .jar is inclusive of other library dependencies (for instance, it contains javassist).
I've a separate project that only takes care about testing classes of that library, but I want to exclude some specific classes and packages from the coverage checks of jacoco.

I'm using maven as package manager, and junit for test cases.

This is my pom for jacoco, line 28 is what I don't know how to write; the official documentation is... sparse to say the least.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <output>file</output>
        <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>myjar.jar</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exlude>myjar.jar/javassist ???</exlude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thanks!